# How to change border width of a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, width, border, axis

How do I change the border width of a `subplot`?

Code is as follows:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (4.1, 2.2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.patch.set_linewidth(0.1) 
ax.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.1)
```

The last two lines do not work, but the following works fine:

```py
legend.get_frame().set_ linewidth(0.1)
```

Answer (score 41):

Maybe this is what you are looking for? It sets the value globally.

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 0.1
```

Answer (score 38):

You want to adjust the border line size? You need to use ax.spines[side].set_linewidth(size).

So something like:

```
[i.set_linewidth(0.1) for i in ax.spines.itervalues()]
```

Comment: In more recent matplotlib it seems ax.spines has no `itervalues` nor `set_linewidth` properties

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me `[x.set_linewidth(1.5) for x in ax.spines.values()]`

Answer (score 0):

If one or more properties of an Artist need to be set to a specific value, matplotlib has a convenience method `plt.setp` (can be used instead of a list comprehension).

```py
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), lw=0.2)
# or
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), linewidth=0.2)
```

Another way is to simply use a loop. Each spine defines a `set()` method that can be used to set a whole host of properties such as linewidth, alpha etc.

```py
for side in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:
    ax.spines[side].set(lw=0.2)
```

A working example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 2))
ax.plot(y)
ax.set(xticks=x, yticks=x, ylim=(0,2), xlim=(0,2));

plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), lw=5, color='red', alpha=0.2);
```

[image: result]