# Make bold the lines around a plot matplotib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I make a plot surrounded with a bold line, like so?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`set_linewidth`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_linewidth) and [`set_color`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_color) parameters from *matplotlib* [`spines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/spines_api.html) :

> An axis spine -- the line noting the data area **boundaries**.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C, W, L, T = "black", 4, 2, 7 # <- adjust here
#Color, Width, Length, Tickness --------------

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(W, L))
list_of_spines = ["left", "right", "top", "bottom"]

for sp in list_of_spines:
    ax.spines[sp].set_linewidth(T)
    ax.spines[sp].set_color(C)

ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code that was the
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639463/matplotlib-border-width)  on a similar question

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
plt.rcParams["axes.edgecolor"] = "black"
plt.rcParams["axes.linewidth"] = 2.50
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (4.1, 2.2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width and colour of a border around the image like so:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# some data for demonstration purposes
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(100)

# create figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x)

# set the border width
fig.set_linewidth(10)

# set the border colour (to black in this case)
fig.set_edgecolor("k")

# show the figure
fig.show()
```

This gives:

[image]